# Get feature's geometry from feature Form's argument

Tags: pyqgis, features

Under a pyqgis form,  the feature from Form's argument doesn't has geometry .
Here the code I used:

```
def formOpen(dialog,layer,feature):
     geometry = feature.geometry()
```

Geometry return is None.

But my feature is multi-point and has a geometry.

To get geom I have to use getFeature from layer with an expression and then it's work. 
like that :

```
    idField = layer.fieldNameIndex('id_field') 
    fcode = feature.attributes()[0]
    request = QgsExpression( "\"id_field\" = '{}' ".format(fcode)) 
    iterator = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(request)) 
    sit = iterator.next()
    geom_buffer = sit.geometry().buffer(20000, -1)
```

with that code I can use the geometry from my feature.
But it's not very effective as I already have the feature from the Form's argument.

Why the feature argument from the formOpen class doesn't has geom ?